# Is a question about finding a video conferencing venue appropriate for SuperUser?

Tags: support, scope

I want to get some advice about how to arrange a venue for confidential video conferencing--home won't work because of a shared living situation, and obviously a wi-fi cafe is far too public.  Is SuperUser the appropriate site to ask this question?  If not, where should I post it?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is a software/hardware related problem, more of a "where it is best to have x" / location problem. My *opinion* is that SU is not the best place for this. Maybe The Workplace would be a better fit, but I don't frequent that stack.
At any rate... it may be hard to get an objective answer, to me it seems like it is quite a subjective and place-dependent question. I suppose you could try the chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about computer hardware or software (we don't provide office chair recommendations either), so it's off topic on Super User.

I don't think there's an appropriate site on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll keep looking for a more appropriate forum.